# elastic4s automatic reconnections when connection is dropped

Tags: elastic4s

Is there a way (or best practice) for handling automatic reconnections in elastic4s?

I have the situation where the elastic cluster gets rebooted behind my application (security updates etc). [Obviously this is not ideal and would be better handled by a rolling restart but we're not quite there yet.]

However when this happens the connection is dropped and never recovers when the cluster comes back online. It keeps saying no nodes are available. If I restart the application it will reconnect without issues.

Is there a way to handle this nicely without having to create a new connection (ie `TcpClient`)? Currently I'd have to distribute the new `TcpClient` to the various parts of the application or wrap the API in something which handles this situation. Neither appeal much.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could consider switching to the `HttpClient`, which will obviously work after a cluster restart because it doesn't maintain a connection. The elastic4s API is the same regardless of which underlying client you are using, so, *in theory*, it should be an easy change.